# Swashbuckle CLI cannot find XML file

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

I am testing the package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli and facing an error when running 
`dotnet swagger "tofile" --output "swagger.json" ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\SwaggerTest.Api.dll" v1`

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Rogier\.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli\5.0.0-rc2\lib\netcoreapp2.0\SwaggerTest.Api.xml'.`

When I move the generated xml from the project folder into `'C:\Users\Rogier\.nuget\packages\swashbuckle.aspnetcore.cli\5.0.0-rc2\lib\netcoreapp2.0\SwaggerTest.Api.xml'` it works fine and swagger.json is created without any errors, but when I remove the file, the xml is missing. Is this a bug in the cli tool that the XML is not copied correctly?

I am using:

- `"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli" Version="5.0.0-rc2"`
- `"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4"`
- `"Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.0.0-rc4"`
- netcoreapp2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. `dotnet swagger "tofile" --output "swagger.json" ".\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\SwaggerTest.Api.dll" v1` had to be changed into `dotnet swagger "tofile" --output "swagger.json" "..\SwaggerTest\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\SwaggerTest.Api.dll" v1`. The swagger.json file is correctly created after this change.

Answer (score 2):

> First, in the project properties, check the box labeled "Generate XML Documentation".
>      [image: xml documentation file]
>
> You will probably also want to suppress warning 1591, which will now give warnings about any method, class, or field that doesn't have triple-slash comments.

[image]

Comment: My settings are similar as yours. The output path and XML documentation file are set as you mentioned. I also set the surpress warning with 1591, although I might remove that one in the future to check if every property is documented as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
  <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);1591</NoWarn>
</PropertyGroup>
```